# Way to give a dedicated executor in master node for the job

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

Is there a way to configure a job that should work with the dedicated executor in the master node. Which means that job should work only with the assigned executor in the master node.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using master for a variety of jobs it is not possible to dedicate one executor out of many to specific job(s). However you can edit the "master" configuration

```
http(s)://YOURJENKINSSERVER/computer/(master)/configure
```

Set Usage to "Leave This Node for Tied Jobs Only" and add a label such as **MASTERONLY**.

Then the job you want to run only in the master would have a restriction to run in **MASTERONLY**

Jobs that do not restrict where they are run will not run on the Master, so effectively you have set aside the master for the jobs the explicitly name the master.

The same technique works for slaves, too.

Follow up: All "Pipeline" (aka [Workflow jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42159221/use-a-lightweight-executor-for-a-declarative-pipeline-stage-agent-none)) run on the Master as a "Flyweight Executor" and then can redirect themselves elsewhere. See the [Jenkins Pipeline Documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/) for help.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think what you are trying to do is possible.

However it looks like that there is something in the pipeline for development which may be a way out for your problem.
[Here is the link.](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-11121)

they suggest a workaround which i think its what you are doing already anyway.

**Current workaround**
use "restrict where this project can be run" for every project. whenever the executor configuration changes each and every project has to be adopted since we do not want to maintain an extra label for each jdk.

I would say the best option is to only set only one executer for your master node as another workaround.

Comment: Note that you can run more than one slave on a machine, so you do not have to be limited to one executor on your master.