# Jenkins / How to deploy with one click

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am working on a project with git and jenkins (pipeline).

I want to build the project at every commit but only deploy it when the chief wants.

So I would like to have like, two pipelines, one that run at every commit and only build / test and one that I can run by clicking on a button labelled "click me to deploy" that do the job.

Do I must create 2 jenkins jobs or is there a plugin or a way to do this with 1 job.

I have searched but I found nothing about this.

Comment: [Insert manual approval](https://superuser.com/questions/1073489/is-there-a-way-to-insert-a-manual-approval-in-jenkins-2-pipelines)

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve with 1job using Input Step (Pipeline). As part of your pipeline, after the build and test execution, add input step (Wait for Interactive input) and then add the deployment related stages.

So for each check-in, Jenkins build will trigger. But it will complete only build and test stages after that it will wait for chief approval to proceed for deployment.

reference: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step

Comment: When using input step make sure you setup your pipeline script properly. BY that i mean decalre agent none in the top of the file and only assign agents to steps other than input. otherwise while the pipeline is running and waiting for human input it will keep one executor busy.

Answer (score -1):

This is an example on how to build a pipeline that builds, waits for input, and deploys when input is yes. If input timeout is exceeded then the job will exit. If one does not need the timeout then it can be ommited and the pipeline will wait indefinately **without consuming an executor** (note the agent annotation in the top pipeline and in each stage)

```
pipeline {
  agent none

stages {
stage('Build') {
  agent { label 'master' }
  steps {
    sh 'build  something'
  }
}


stage('Production deploy confirmation') {
    options {
      timeout(time: 60, unit: 'SECONDS')
    }
    input {
        message "Deploy to production?"
        ok "Yes"
    }
    steps {
      echo 'Confirmed production deploy'
    }
}


stage('Deploy Production') {

    stage('internal') {
      agent { label 'master' }
      steps {
        sh 'deploy something'
      }
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try a parametrized Job with a Boolean parameter and two separate stages for *Build* and *Deploy*:

```
pipeline{
    parameters {            
        booleanParam(name: 'deploy_param', defaultValue: false, description: 'Check if want to deploy')     
    }
    stages{
        stage("Build"){
            steps{
                // build steps
            }
        }    
        stage("Deploy"){
            when {
                environment name: 'deploy_param', value: 'true'
            }
            steps{
                // deploy steps
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this way yo can have a CI build with "Deploy" stage turned off, as the *deploy_param* is set to *false* **by default**. And also a manual build ("when the chief wants") with "Deploy" stage turned on by manually setting the *deploy_param* to *true*.

Comment: This is not what the OP needs. The build is triggered by git commit not manually so you cant change the boolean parameters.

Comment: @marxmacher In my solution you have both: automatic build with default value for booleanParam deploy = false and a manual build with a deployment step "when the chief wants". ;)

Comment: But what happens it "chief" wants to deploy an already build job? rebuild? rerun from stage? Seems a hassle compared to having a input step.

Comment: @marxmacher You can achieve a Build with only a  "Deploy" stage without a "Build" stage just by adding one more param. The big disadvantage of having an input step is that your job will be blocking your node the whole time until a user interaction or a timeout for the input. And that every time you made a commit!
In my solution you do not have this disadvantage.

Comment: Common mistake - blocking node. If implemented correctly no executors will be held during input step :)

Comment: Here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42561241/how-to-wait-for-user-input-in-a-declarative-pipeline-without-blocking-a-heavywei

Comment: @marxmacher Still, I do not see the proove of your first comment "This is not what the OP needs." And I disagree the downvote. You can easely achieve what the OP wants using my solution as I described above.

Comment: "I want to build the project at every commit but only deploy it when the chief wants."
Your solution means either build only or rerun job and build + deploy. this is consuming more resources than needed (builder time to build same artefact twice) If you would add a parameter to your script where you could put in the build number you want to deploy then it would be some what closer to what the OP needed but still not it. 

The only correct way to achieve what the OP needed is using the pipeline input step to get the input. If the OP is ok with running jobs twice then its another thing.

Comment: @marxmacher
1) OP literally wants two pipelines *"I would like to have like, **two pipelines**, one that run at every commit and only build / test and one that I can run by clicking on a button labelled "click me to deploy" that do the job."*
2) In both solutioins with input step and with a boolean parameter you **need** to interact with the build. So their are both equally good or bad in terms of automatisation.